# Nested italics in HTML

Tags: html

How can one deal with nested italics in HTML?

I have a page entitled "The *Display* Menu" (`The <i>Display</i> Menu`). I now want to reference this page in italics, which should therefore become *The* Display *Menu*, but instead becomes *The *Display* Menu* (`<i>The <i>Display</i> Menu</i>`). In order to have this print correctly, the code must be changed to `<i>The </i>Display<i> Menu</i>`. The same behavior is present with `<em>`.

Is there a way to make the italics toggle between off and on when nested?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to define an appropriate CSS rule:

```
i i {
    font-style: normal;
}
```